# Installing GPS device Explorist Magellan 210 (ca 2005) on Windows 8?

Tags: gps, installation, windows-8

Windows is unable to reckognize my device. It's 10 years old but fully functionnal.
I would at least make it work as an external disk.

[image: GPS device]

Comment: How are you connecting to the PC? Serial port? USB? Ideally, how do you want to see it work?

Comment: You can use 'ExpertGPS' supports windows 8 http://www.expertgps.com/gps-receivers/Magellan-eXplorist-210.asp

Comment: @Mapperz It works fine with ExpertGPS. You get me out of a tricky situation. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at GPS Splitter from [GPSGate](http://gpsgate.com/). I use it to connect my Garmin via USB to a Windows 8 laptop and stream NMEA data. Your question doesn't provide specifics so I'm not sure what exactly you need / want.

Comment: @DenalilHardtail The device is connected with the USB port. I would like it to be reckognized as a simple external disk so that I can download the GPXs files. Thank you.